# client side performance testing

Tags: performance

i wanted to test web based software where java script play significant role.i want to check the performance ,can anyone suggest good tool. also iwant to automate the same.

Note : iam using jmeter for performance testing now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Yslow in firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

Comment: thanks for your response ,i wanted to make automated setup with the tool .is it possible with yslow?

Comment: You can test your page with Yslow right away. Also it gives you some suggestions to make better performance on your page.

Comment: i want to check the performance of js more .i want to know when js hangs or takes more time to respond etc.

Answer (score 0):

With Firebug, you can use

```
console.time("name");
console.timeEnd("name");
```

or

```
console.profile();
console.profileEnd();
```

around a specific block of JS

I guess you could write a firebug plugin to somewhat automate it but it's more for looking for specific things.